# Sql server join 3 tables and get the latest from 3rd table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi all I am having 3 tables as follows

```
Technology_table

Technology_ID     Technology_Name
  10                Asp.Net
  20                  C#

Question_table

QUESTION_ID     Technology_ID    QUESTION_DESCRIPTION
  1                 10            First ques in Asp.net
  2                 20            First ques in C#

Reply_table

QUESTION_ID     Technology_ID    Reply_Date       Reply_Message
  1                 10            2016-01-23        I am first to post
  1                 10            2016-01-24        I am second to post
```

I have written the following query but not getting the result as expected

```
select
   FI.QUESTION_ID,FI.QUESTION_TITLE,FI.USER_NAME,FI.DATE_POSTED,
   FI.[DATE_REPLIED],FI.RepliedName,FI.VIEW_COUNT,FI.REPLY_COUNT,
  FI.REPLY_MESSAGE,TT.TECHNOLOGY_ID,TT.TECHNOLOGY_NAME
from FORUM_TECHNOLOGY TT,
(  select distinct
     TQ.TECHNOLOGY_ID,TQ.QUESTION_ID,TQ.QUESTION_TITLE,TQ.USER_NAME,
     TQ.DATE_POSTED,
     TR.[DATE_REPLIED],
     TR.USER_NAME as RepliedName,
     TQ.VIEW_COUNT,TQ.REPLY_COUNT,TR.REPLY_MESSAGE
   from  FORUM_QUESTIONS TQ
   LEFT OUTER JOIN FORUM_REPLIES TR
       ON TR.TECHNOLOGY_ID=TQ.TECHNOLOGY_ID
      and TR.QUESTION_ID = TQ.QUESTION_ID 
      and TR.[DATE_REPLIED] in (
          select MAX(TR.[DATE_REPLIED])
          from FORUM_REPLIES TR
          group by TR.QUESTION_ID
       )
) FI
where FI.TECHNOLOGY_ID =TT.TECHNOLOGY_ID
  and TT.TECHNOLOGY_ID = @TechID
```

I also tried in this way

```
select t1.QUESTION_ID,oa.USER_NAME,oa.REPLY_MESSAGE
from FORUM_QUESTIONS t1
cross apply(select top 1 * from FORUM_REPLIES 
            where QUESTION_ID = t1.QUESTION_ID
            order by DATE_REPLIED desc)oa
join FORUM_TECHNOLOGY t2 on oa.TECHNOLOGY_ID = t2.TECHNOLOGY_ID 
AND oa.QUESTION_ID = t1.QUESTION_ID
```

I would like to display only one instead of duplicates
[image]

Can some one help me

Comment: use distinct cluase in select ..

Comment: Tried that too it didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that your DATE_REPLIED has a valid time component and isn't just omitted or defaulted to midnight.

```
SELECT FQ.QUESTION_ID
        , FQ.QUESTION_TITLE
        , FQ.USER_NAME
        , FQ.DATE_POSTED
        , FR.DATE_REPLIED
        , FR.RepliedName
        , FQ.VIEW_COUNT
        , FI.REPLY_COUNT
        , FR.REPLY_MESSAGE
        , TT.TECHNOLOGY_ID
        , TT.TECHNOLOGY_NAME
FROM FORUM_TECHNOLOGY AS TT
INNER JOIN FORUM_QUESTION AS FQ
        ON FQ.TECHNOLOGY_ID = TT.TECHNOLOGY_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT QUESTION_ID
                , COUNT(*) AS REPLY_COUNT
                , MAX(DATE_REPLIED) AS DATE_REPLIED
        FROM FORUM_REPLIES
        GROUP BY QUESTION_ID
        ) AS FI
        ON FI.QUESTION_ID = FQ.QUESTION_ID
INNER JOIN FORUM_REPLIES AS FR
        ON FR.QUESTION_ID = FI.QUESTION_ID
                AND FR.DATE_REPLIED = FI.DATE_REPLIED
```

Comment: Getting the following exception `The multi-part identifier "FI.DATE_REPLIED" could not be bound.
`

Comment: Still I am getting duplicates

Comment: Are they actual duplicates or just 2 different replies with the exact same DATE_REPLIED? Also, does the FORUM_REPLIES table have an ID column and if so is it an SQL identity? You may be able to use MAX on the ID instead of the DATE_REPLIED.